# QnA Maker service is not showing in "My knowledge Bases"

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I am following [this tutorial](https://www.qnamaker.ai/Create) and made a QnA service on Azure but it is not showing in "My Knowledge Bases".

Answer (score 1):

Azure QnA service just get api key and QnA API service 
if you want to create Knowledge Bases  pls go to https://www.qnamaker.ai/ , that will link your QnA API service on Azure in setting option .

Answer (score 0):

Did you create QnAMaker service or a knowledge base.

First do this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/how-to/set-up-qnamaker-service-azure

And then create a knowledge base: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/how-to/create-knowledge-base

Comment: I did all this, and yet it is not showing up as service in the dropdown on the qnamaker.ai page...

Answer (score 0):

Azure needs some time to deploy everything. Follow the steps here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/how-to/set-up-qnamaker-service-azure

Open the deployment tab in azure and make sure it says "Your deployment is complete". If it does not: try removing the service and recreate it.

Afterwards it should become visible in the dropdown on the qnamaker.ai page.